# PySpark broadcast variables for networkx library

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, networkx

I am new to Spark and exploring its features. I'm building for an algorithm using networkx library and I'm attempting to create broadcast variables for networkx variables.

My networkx looks like such:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_edgelist(path="data.txt", create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)
```

And I have broadcast variable:

```
Gbc = sc.broadcast(G)
```

My simple method will be distributed across the spark cluster?, as:

```
def getEgoGraphNodes(u):
    return Gbc.value.neighbors(u)
```

Then, When I do my map:

```
vertices=set(G) #list vertices
verticeRDD = sc.parallelize(vertices) #create RDD
verticeRDD.map(lambda x: getEgoGraphNodes(x)).collect()
```

I get the following error: (Although i installed networkx library on workers)

```
17/05/22 00:06:11 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 31, 192.168.100.9, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in getEgoGraphNodes
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 106, in value
    self._value = self.load(self._path)
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 97, in load
    return pickle.load(f)
ImportError: No module named 'networkx'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/05/22 00:06:11 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 2 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
17/05/22 00:06:12 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.2 in stage 2.0 (TID 43, 192.168.100.9, executor 0): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 809, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 42, 192.168.100.9, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in getEgoGraphNodes
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 106, in value
    self._value = self.load(self._path)
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 97, in load
    return pickle.load(f)
ImportError: No module named 'networkx'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in getEgoGraphNodes
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 106, in value
    self._value = self.load(self._path)
  File "/usr/local/spark/2.1.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 97, in load
    return pickle.load(f)
ImportError: No module named 'networkx'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more

>>> 17/05/22 00:06:12 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.2 in stage 2.0 (TID 41, 192.168.100.9, executor 0): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
17/05/22 00:06:12 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 44, 192.168.100.9, executor 1): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

It has returned the following error - ImportError: No module named 'networkx'

Just try to install it

```
%pip install networkx
```